# How to post to a Facebook fan page using fb sdk in IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating an app and that app has a FB fan page. For all Users of app need to post on that app's fan page using the app. How can I do this? Can any one help?

Comment: Do you want to post Image or message?

Comment: I want to post a message.

Comment: Please refer this blog.. https://www.parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios

Comment: That blog doesn't have the content what I looking for? :(

Answer (score 0):

the app's fan page is yours, I assume, and you're trying to have people post on that app fan page, if I interpret correctly. If it is so, you're trying to post on your own fan page. Get the access token for your fan page with `GET` HTTP call (cURL for me) at the url https://graph.facebook.come/YOURID/accounts (or use the Graph Explorer tool to see what that is. Use that token, that never expires for you (if you're the admin), to post, with a `POST` HTTP request to https://graph.facebook.come/PERSONID/feed. I hope this is the answer to your question.